# FinancialData missing data for April 7 and April 8 2020 for many if not all US Stocks

Tags: curated-data, finance

```
FinancialData["IBM", {2020, 4, 3}]["Dates"]
```

The above command yields:

```
    {DateObject[{2020, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -7.], 
     DateObject[{2020, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -7.], 
     DateObject[{2020, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -7.]}
```

Note April 7 and 8 missing.

Comment: Interesting finding, but where is the question? I think you are mistaking this site for an official site by Wolfram Research. It is not. We cannot change the curated data. Please contact Wolfram Support about it.

Comment: it seems to be missing for all stocks, not just IBM.

Answer (score 1):

> Note April 7 and 8 missing.

it is working now. It seems to have been just some data delay of some sort for those days before.  Here is current output (V 12.1 on windows)

```
 FinancialData["IBM", {2020, 4, 3}]["Dates"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for checking this out.  Yes, I now see all the data.  Will have to remember for the future in case this delay happens again.  Regards.